# Azure SDK not available on Hosted VS2017 VSTS Build Agent?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, build-agent

Our .Net projects are using VS 2017, and requires **Azure Storage Emulator** in Azure SDK to run unit tests.
Our CI/CD is running in VSTS. We want to use some hosted build agent in VSTS agent pools. There are two issues we encountered.
Firstly, according to official document, **Hosted VS2017** [seems don't have Azure SDK installed](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted#hosted-vs2017).
Secondly, when running command **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe start**, it failed with **Error: Unable to start the storage emulator**.

Comment: The Azure SDK is available on Hosted VS 2017 agent, you can add Command Line task to check it: Tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe; Arguments: init /server (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDb.

Comment: What's the detail scenario of your issue and what's the error?

Comment: There seem to be two issues.
First, unlike Hosted agent the official document doesn't say that Azure SDK is installed on Hosted VS2017 agent. Second, command **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe start** fails probably due to insufficient permission.

Answer (score 0):

The VSTS Hosted agent is running as service that you can’t start storage emulator (init is ok).

Check the related thread: [Failed to start AzureStorageEmulator on VSTS Hosted VS2017 Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345563/failed-to-start-azurestorageemulator-on-vsts-hosted-vs2017-agent)

Answer (score 0):

I've been running the Azure Storage Emulator on a VS2017 hosted build agent for a long time now.

The trick is to initialise SQL LocalDB first (the emulator uses it), and then start the emulator. You can do this with a command line task that runs:

```
sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start
```