# Failed to start AzureStorageEmulator on VSTS Hosted VS2017 Agent

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, build-agent

We have .Net project build definition on VSTS and it's using Azure Storage Emulator for running tests. And we want to use Hosted 2017 agents for the build definition.

I saw this question ([Azure SDK not available on Hosted VS2017 VSTS Build Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108199/azure-sdk-not-available-on-hosted-vs2017-vsts-build-agent)) and the comment that I can use command "***C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe init /server (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDb***" to initialize Azure Storage Emulator.

However, when I tried to start Azure Storage Emulator with command "***C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe start***", it failed with **Error: Unable to start the storage emulator**.

Is there any way to start Azure Storage Emulator on VSTS Hosted 2017 agent?

[Command and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcJ5T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now possible.

## See the other answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51726177/1830814

### Some more info here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/238481/hosted-visual-studio-2017-errorno-available-sql-in.html#

Answer (score 0):

The VSTS Hosted agent is running as service that you can’t start storage emulator (init is ok).

A related thread: [VSO Hosted Build Controller - Is the Azure Storage Emulator supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723795/vso-hosted-build-controller-is-the-azure-storage-emulator-supported)

Update:

Based on the test, the Azure Storage Emulator can be started on Hosted VS2017 agent now.

Comment: What test are you referring to?

Comment: @GGirard Calling AzureStorageEmulator.exe start during the build/release with Hosted VS2017 agent.